# Magento 2 product quantity increasing automatically

Tags: magento2, product, bug, qty-increment

I have Magento 2.2.7, the issue is when I update product quantity to zero "0", it automatically increments the quantity after some time. I tried on 3 products and each products increment was different. I checked in logs, none were generated, checked product update time, that too also isn't changing after the automatic increment. Any guesses, how can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the solution is this link:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12483

Comment: just commented out sales_clean_orders cron in vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/crontab.xml